# How do I display new products AUTOMATICALLY on the Magento home-page?

Tags: magento

I need to display 3 or so new products automatically on the Magento home-page. This means the administrator should NOT have to mark the product as new using the 'New from Date' and 'New to Date' attributes in the 'General' tab. I know how to create a separate category containing new products automatically (http://www.tridian.com/developer-blog/adding-new-arrivals-to-magento/), but how do I display them on the home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a new model for such system attribute. 
First of all edit your *eav_attribute* table in magento mysql database

Go edit "news_to_date" record and set backend model 
from "eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime" to "catalog/product_attribute_backend_newsto"

Now go to Core/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend and create a new file "Newsto.php"

write this code in this file than save

```
   class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Newsto extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Datetime
{
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $attributeName  = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
        $startDate      = $object->getData('news_from_date');
        $toDate         = $object->getData($attributeName);

        if ($toDate === false) {
            return $this;
        }
        if ($toDate == '' && $startDate != '') {          
        $newdate = strtotime($startDate);             
        $toDate = date("d/m/Y",strtotime("+7 days",$newdate));
        }

        $object->setData($attributeName, $toDate);

        parent::beforeSave($object);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can if you build a custom layout for your homepage and choose to display stuff there not based on new criteria but based on a given category. Never done this so its just a suggestion to research in this direction.